# How can I configure the default settings of RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

I launch RStudio in a Docker container and access to it via the browser in the host OS. I prefer the settings **Console on Right** and **Emacs Key Bindings**, so usually check these options by hand in GUI. The container does not share the home directory where .rstudio/ directory stands, every time I destroy the container, those settings are lost.

I suspect there's a options or global configuration files that make my preferable settings default.

How can I configure the default settings of RStudio ?

[image: console on right]

Comment: I am not familiar with your R environment.  But have you tried setting the working directory and other desired defaults in the .Rprofile file of your projects?

Comment: @SteveM Thank you for your reply. Probably my question was misleading. I want to configure not about R process but the RStudio server settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no supported way to do this in RStudio 1.2, but RStudio 1.3 (which will be available soon) makes it possible. You can try a daily build of RStudio 1.3 here:

https://dailies.rstudio.com/

Specifically, you will want to put your settings in `/etc/rstudio/rstudio-prefs.json`, as described here:

https://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/latest/r-sessions.html#customizing-session-settings

To figure out what exactly to put in that file to get the layout and keybindings you want, I recommend setting up RStudio the way you want it by hand, then copying the config out of the `~/.config/rstudio/rstudio-prefs.json` file.

There is also documentation on everything you can set in the admin guide:

https://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/latest/session-user-settings.html

(The admin guide is for the professional version, but all of the above also applies to the open source edition.)